# Copying files using MTP leads to 99% disk utilization

Tags: windows-10, performance, android, file-transfer, mtp

Since Android phones are no longer mounted as an external drive I'm having an issue with a copying of large amount of photos from the phone (no matter what - LG G3, Galaxy S7) to the laptop (Windows 10).

It starts at pretty good speed - I can see file name changing 3-4 times per second in the copying dialog - and then getting slower and slower till the moment when single file name could be displayed for up to 10 sec.

I would probably just live with it but I found that laptop's performance degrades as well during this process as copying brings 99% disk utilization while transfer speed is far below the maximum for the SSD:

[image: 99% Disk utilization with transfer speed of 1.4MB/s]

How to track down and fix the reason it is happening?

Comment: I use FTP now all the time to transfer data between phone/PC

Comment: I saw this since you are using android,  claims there are less problems using MTP:  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.clearevo.mtp_alternative&hl=en  Haven't tried it myself though, gl.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this answer:

- https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88255/ultra-slow-speed-while-transfer-files-between-pc-and-samsung-s5

This is a problem in communication's protocol:

> The MTP and PTP standards do not support direct modification of objects. Modified objects must be copied out of the device and reuploaded in their entirety, which can take a long time for large objects

And Based on this article:

- https://vxlabs.com/2014/11/06/use-adb-to-bypass-dog-slow-mtp-transfer-of-files-from-android-to-linux/

It suggests to use ADB to transfer files, but in Linux not Windows 10.

To use ADB on Windows, follow this:

- http://www.howtogeek.com/125769/how-to-install-and-use-abd-the-android-debug-bridge-utility/

Comment: Does the quote imply that copying without modification should work well?

Comment: work well ? yes! work fast ? no! "...which can take a long time for large objects"